# SASS mixin using SASS rgba() function not working with interpolation

Tags: sass, rgba

The SASS documentation says [rgba](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgb-instance_method) function can be called in 2 ways.

I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/KerryRuddock/pen/xqqxOP?editors=1100%20%22codepen) to demonstrate the rgba function in a mixin I am having problems with:

```
$hd-color1: #366dbd;    // heading color
$hd-shadow1: 0.24;      // text shadow opacity

@mixin ColorAndTextShadow($color, $opacity) {
  color: $color;
  text-shadow: 3px 1px rgba( #{$color}, #{$opacity} );
}

h2 {
  @include ColorAndTextShadow ( #{$hd-color1}, #{$hd-shadow1} );
  font-family: Circular, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**Thanks in advance for taking a look**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's just a syntax error. You can pass in the variables in directly.

Please see the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZZXzY?editors=1100%20%22codepen)

```
$hd-color1: #366dbd;    // heading color
$hd-shadow1: 0.24;      // text shadow opacity

@mixin ColorAndTextShadow($color, $opacity) {
  color: $color;
  text-shadow: 3px 1px rgba($color, $opacity );
}

h2 {
  @include ColorAndTextShadow ( $hd-color1, $hd-shadow1 );
  font-family: Circular, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: That worked.  I removed the interpolation from mixin but not from the @include in an earlier attempt to get it to work.  Thank you.